# Do I need to use RSelenium to download these PDFs?

Tags: r, selenium, rvest, rselenium, pdftools

I am trying to use rvest and pdftools to go through [this page](https://northernbrucepeninsula.civicweb.net/filepro/documents/50416) and download the PDFs. I'm having trouble using CSS selector to do this, and wondering if this might take a webdriver?

Also, is it easy enough to use a webdriver to do this in R - as a bit of a beginner R user?

Comment: Maybe try `xpath` instead of `CSS`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution could be `download.file()` function.

Suppose that we have detected all files links and we have a list.

```
url <- "https://northernbrucepeninsula.civicweb.net/filepro/documents/?preview=56705"

download.file(url, destfile, quiet = TRUE)
```

`url` = the link of the file that you want to donwload.

`destfile` = a character string (or vector, see url) with the name where the downloaded file is saved. Tilde-expansion is performed.

`quiet` = If TRUE, suppress status messages (if any), and the progress bar.